# Remove outermost parentheses

Tags: regex, parentheses, openrefine, grel

I am having problem while removing outermost parentheses from a string using GREL. What i am trying to do is simply remove outermost parentheses and all other parentheses should be kept intact. Below is what i am trying to do using regex -

```
value.split(/(abc+/)
```

and below is my sample string that i am trying to parse and desired output.

```
Foo ( test1 test2 ) => Foo test1 test2
Bar ( test1 t3() test2 ) => Bar test1 t3() test2
Baz ((("Fdsfds"))) => Baz (("Fdsfds"))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i have edited my question. It's in GREL

Comment: you can try this `str.replace(/\)(.*?)$/, "$1")`

Comment: @CodeManiac i don't know if str.replace would work in GREL but since the logic is same i did value.replace(/\)(.*?)$/,' ') but now it is removing ending parentheses only and starting parentheses is still there. So this string Baz ((("Fdsfds"))) looks like this Baz ((("Fdsfds"

Comment: You can decide to remove the first paranthesis then the last  eg `^[^(]*\K\(|\)(?=[^)]*$)`

Comment: @JonAbraham you can use this `/^(.*?)\((.*)\)(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3" seee here [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9LHRK/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to use a capturing group and in the replacement use the first capturing group.

Note that this does not take balanced parenthesis into account.

It matches the outer parenthesis, then captures in a group what is inside and matches an outer parenthesis again.

Inside the capturing group is an alternation that matches not `()` or from an openening till closing parenthesis.

```
\((\(*(?:[^)(]*|\([^)]*\))*\)*)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match outer parenthesis `(`
- `(` Capture group
  -`\(*` Match 0+ times `(`

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[^)(]*` Match 0+ times not `(` or `)`
    - `|` Or
    - `\([^)]*\)` Match from `(` till next `)` closing parenthesis
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\)*` Match 0+ times a closing parenthesis
- `)` Close capture group
- `\)` Match outer closing parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DyFsGD/1)

Comment: This is indeed a way to do it without having to play with negative lookbehind/lookahead

Comment: thank you very much for giving this idea and also. I am going to mark this as an answer and +1 for explanation. I learned a bit about regex here

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar at all with `grel` or `openrefine` regex syntax or limitation, in a broader context you can use one of the following regexes depending on what regex engine is used.

**PCRE regex:**

```
^[^(]*\K\(|\)(?!.*\).*)
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/lj0Qbl/1/

**ECMA regex:**

```
(?<!.*\(.*)\(|\)(?!.*\).*)
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/g8XbjI/1/

for both:

**Input:**

```
Foo ( test1 test2 ) bob
Bar ( test1 t3() test2 ) bob
Baz ((("Fdsfds"))) bob
```

**Output:**

```
Foo  test1 test2  bob
Bar  test1 t3() test2  bob
Baz (("Fdsfds")) bob
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this with GREL. If you want to use regular expressions then in GREL I'd recommend combining this with the GREL `match` function:

```
value.match(/(.*?)\((.*)\)(.*)/).join("")
```

Note that this expression assumes there is at least one pair of parentheses in the cell - cells that have no parentheses or have only an opening or only a closing parentheses will give an error - however you can use the option 'on error keep original' (which is the default) when doing a cell transformation to keep the original value in these cases

Answer (score 1):

If our inputs are all similar to those listed in the question, this expression might work:

```
(.+?)\s+\((\s+)?(.*)(\s+)?\)
```

and we would replace it with `$1 $3`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DwZJ6W/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]